# I get "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'" when running simple query

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I run this code from my application I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

If I copy / paste it into SQL and substitute a file name it returns a value without issue. There are other statements in the same class that are functioning properly although they are `INSERT` or `UPDATE` requests.

```
string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString;
string queryString = $@"SELECT [THJobId] FROM [LLid] WHERE [filename] = '{fileName}'";

IDbCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString);
IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection;
dbConnection.Open();

var result = dbCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Apart from the SQL Injection vector I can't see anything wrong here.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injections. Consider using [parameterized queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: Use a debugger and tell us what's the value of `queryString`. My bet is the `fileName` contains characters that break the query, such as single quotes `'`. (using parameterized queries will fix that)

Comment: Well I've updated my query so that it now looks as follows:

`string queryString = $@"SELECT [THJobId] FROM [LLid] WHERE [filename] = @filename";`

and added the following parameter info:

`IDataParameter dbParam_filename = new SqlParameter();`
`dbParam_filename.ParameterName  = "@filename";`
`dbParam_filename.Value = fileName;`
`dbParam_filename.DbType = DbType.String;`
`dbCommand.Parameters.Add(dbParam_filename);`

However I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Also in regards to the single quotes, none appear in the filename variable.  The name contains a hyphen, underscore and period, but nothing else.

Comment: It's not possible the above parameterized query is giving you that exact error message. Is this your *exact* query? I suspect you are not giving us the full thing. Side point: you should dispose `dbConnection` and `dbCommand` with `using`.